# Is the Potassium Sodium pump a part of the process that creates gastric acid?

Tags: digestion, biochemistry

From my research I understand that the H+/K+ ATPase pump is the main mechanism of acidification of the gastric fluids and that blocking its operation reduces the amount of stomach acid.

I also understand that the stomach starts with a mix of Na+ and K+ and these ions get replaced with H+. I can't find any reference to how the Na+ is removed.  My assumption is that the body uses a Potassium, Sodium pump to replace the Sodium with Potassium and then replace the Potassium with Hydrogen.

Is that a correct conclusion?

Comment: What is making you think sodium is removed? It's helpful to cite and even briefly quote from the sources you read in your question.

Comment: There are multitudes of transporters in the GI tract for each of sodium and potassium. For most of these, retaining the concentration of ions in a certain range, especially in the cells and interstitia (the space between the cells and blood vessels) is critical. The concentration of ions in the lumen will depend a lot on what you eat. Ultimately, you have hundreds of circuits at work like the one you mentioned, some more important than others. It thus becomes impossible to satisfactorily answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

Because the E-qualification of ans seeker are not known; i would attempt to answer from the basics but before i attempt to answer, comment by @M.A.R. is most appropriate unless someone cites some research article with the question in context. yet your query **seems** to be the evolution aspect  but i **could not understand what you mean by "stomach starts with a mix of Na+ and K+ and these ions get replaced with H+."** what is source or reference of this statement.

Now the ans attempt - In Evolutionary Aspect - query seems to be how structural evolution of channel proteins specifies cation selectivity of channels & pumps which may be answered as in ["Structure and function of H+/K+ pump mutants reveal Na+/K+ pump mechanisms"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/36085139/) - quoting "Ion-transport mechanisms evolve by changing ion-selectivity, such as switching from Na+ to H+ selectivity in **secondary-active transporters** or P-type-ATPases." but these are in secondary active transport context. while humans gastric acid secretion uses H+-, K+-ATPase (gastric; H+ efflux; K+ uptake) - Two H3O+ may be transported per ATP hydrolyzed which is primary active transport.

Quoting another reference ["Gastric H+-translocating ATPases (ouabain-insensitive) comprise a ***subgroup*** of the larger and more diverse ***Na+/K+ ATPase family*** (ouabain-sensitive) (Family 1)."](https://tcdb.org/search/result.php?tc=3.A.3).
Further quoting "The gastric H+-translocating ATPases replace H+ for K+ but with an H+/K+ stoichiometry of 2:2. Thus, although these two enzymes are ~***65% identical***, the Na+,K+-ATPases are electrogenic while the H+,K+-ATPases are electroneutral. Gastric H+, K+-ATPase transports 2 moles of H+ together with two H2O (two H3O+) per mole of ATP hydrolyzed in isolated hog gastric vesicles."[2](https://tcdb.org/search/result.php?tc=3.A.3).
You can dig deeper using references for [detailed mechanism , and the roles of essential residues](https://tcdb.org/search/result.php?acc=P51164&tc=3.A.3.1.2)